# For some reason, images aren't rendering on a Vercel app even though they render on localhost

Tags: reactjs, typescript, image, jpeg, vercel

Here's the repo:
https://github.com/DanielRLi0505/Magic-Den-Recipe-Finder-for-Boba-Story

And the images are in /public/icons.

I even did some configurations to next.config.js, and still nothing.  The images show up perfectly on localhost, but they won't show up on the Vercel deployment.  Anyone have any suggestions?  Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.